# Create frames at runtime

Tags: forms, vcl, frames

I need to create frames at runtime, there are 44 frames so I intend to use multithreading for that. Now we have 44 Tabsheets on PageControls which takes so long to load.

But I can not.

The idea is as follows:

I have OnCreate from my main form:

```
procedure TFConfMERC.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

 //Here you should instantiate the threads that will instantiate the frames and then only proceed with the main thread when all other threads have instantiated the frames of this form

end;
```

Is it possible to implement this?

I need threads because the form takes 20 seconds to open, and we need to improve performance on this.

OBS: This code works on Delphi 11, but it gets stuck in Delphi XE 7.

```
var
  Tasks: Array[0..1] of ITask;
begin
  Tasks[0] := TTask.Create(procedure
                            begin
                              frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Self); //stuck here
                              frame2.parent  := TabSheet1;
                              sleep(5000);
                            end);

  Tasks[1] := TTask.Create(procedure
                            begin
                              frame3 := TFrame3.Create(Self); //stuck here
                              frame3.parent  := TabSheet2;
                              sleep(5000);
                            end);
  Tasks[0].Start;
  Tasks[1].Start;

  TTask.WaitForAll(Tasks);
```

Comment: You can't create `TFrame` objects from outside of the main UI thread. All of your `TTask`s would have to synchronize with the main UI thread, thus serializing the actions, which defaults the purpose of using `TTask` at all.  Rather than having the `TTask`s create the `TFrame` objects themselves, they should just load the *data* that the `TFrame`s need. Create the actual `TFrame` objects in the main UI thread, and make they refer to the loaded data as needed.

Comment: i dont have data to load to the frame, i just need create them.
but as we have 44 tabs, even delphi IDE takes long time to load the form.

so the idea was using thread for this.

the example with TTask does not work in delphi xe 7.

please see the code below and help me get it better

Answer (score -1):

Here is the problem solved!!!!!! =D

```
  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    var
      T1: TThread;
      T2: TThread;
      FSemaforo: TSemaphore;
    begin
      FSemaforo := TSemaphore.Create(nil, 2, 2, '');
      T1 := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
                                         begin
                                           FSemaforo.Acquire;
                                           try
                                             TThread.Sleep(5000); //Teste de paralelismo
                                             TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
                                             procedure
                                             begin
                                               frame3 := TFrame3.Create(Self);
                                               frame3.Parent  := Panel2;
                                             end);
                                           finally
                                             FSemaforo.Release;
                                           end;
                                         end);
    
      T2 := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(procedure
                                         begin
                                           FSemaforo.Acquire;
                                           try
                                             TThread.Sleep(5000); //Teste de paralelismo
                                             TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
                                             procedure
                                             begin
                                               frame2 := TFrame2.Create(Self);
                                               frame2.Parent  := Panel1;
                                             end);
                                           finally
                                             FSemaforo.Release;
                                           end;
                                         end);
      T1.FreeOnTerminate := False;
      T2.FreeOnTerminate := False;
      T1.Start;
      T2.Start;
      {wait the threads to finish, then proceed =D}
      while (not t1.Finished) or (not t2.Finished) do
      begin
        Application.ProcessMessages;
      end;
    
      T1.Free;
      T2.Free;
      FSemaforo.Free;
    end;
```

Comment: Guys, I'm trying to improve the code, how to make it more generic. Someone help me ? I tried but it's not working.

Comment: This code is *horrible*. Don't use it. This is not a good way to write multi-threaded logic. You need to re-write this.

Comment: can you help me ? I'm a thread noob, imagine multi-threading....I need help, threads can't instantiate frames ? here it works.

Could you give me a better idea?

Comment: please, I need to fire X threads in parallel and each one of them will instantiate frames, that's all. Does anyone have a better way to do this?

Comment: if I keep everything accountable for the main thread it won't solve the screen opening performance problem.

Comment: Since UI controls can't be created outside of the UI thread, adding worker threads won't help you. You need to change your UI design. For example, just because you have 44 tabs doesn't mean you need to create all 44 frames at one time. The user will only see one at a time, so create them on-demand as the user is switching tabs. For example, the user sees Tab 1 initially, so create only Frame 1 immediately. When the user switches to, say, Tab 5 next, then create Frame 5, and optionally destroy Frame 1 until the next time the user goes to Tab 1. And so on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, understood. But this way, i will need to rewrite all the logic behind the form =/ but thanks